# Difference between Process and Practice in Information Security

Tags: terminology

I'm learning from the ["Information Security"](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9781315288697) book and already know what the two terms *policy* and *procedure* mean.

While these two terms are quite easy to distinguish:

*policy* is what to do to secure the data and the information system, whereas *procedure* refers to the steps about how the policy should be enforced.

I came across another two terms: *process* and *practice*. There is a book using these 2 terms  and the term policy as the book titled ["Information Security"](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9781315288697). In the sense of English, I suppose these two terms have similar meaning with procedure.

I'm not quite sure what the **main** difference is between *process* and *practice* in an Information Security point of view. In addition, when *process* and *practice* are added together, do they have the same meaning as *procedure* or does this rather depend on the context?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you've already got it. Like you mentioned, process is what "should" be done, and practice is what is actually done (akin to theory vs. practice). Try not to get mixed up in minutia like this, though. There are no hard and fast definitions between the terms, and if anyone is being pedantic, just ask them what they're actually talking about.